# How to create a nested ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a WEB API that is working fine. I want to call an action that is a part of my API via Ajax request. It seems that it is easy and I had it working for simple requests. However, I tried to put nested calls and for some reason the data that is passed to the second request gets lost. I was wondering if it is a scope problem or something I did wrong in my code.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$("#submit_request").click(function () {
        var firstName = $("#first_name").val();
        var lastName = $("#last_name").val();
        var faciltiy = $("#facility").val();

        // Collecting all the documents into an array of JSON
        var documents = [];

        var request = JSON.stringify({
            "PatientFirstName": firstName,
            "PatientLastName": lastName,
            "Facility": faciltiy
        });

        //the first request is working fine and it has a success state
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:64611/api/requests/createRequest",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: request,
            success: function (request_id, state) {


      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         var RequestDocument = {
            "RequestID": i,
            "DocumentID": i+1,
            "StartDate": Date(),
            "EndDate": Date()
         };

         documents.push(RequestDocument);

      }
                console.log(documents); // it is returning a correct object
                console.log(typeof (documents)); // type object

                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:64611/api/requests/addDocumentsOfARequest/",
                    type: "post",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    contenttype: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(documents), ---> this object should be passed to the api action
                    success: function (response, state) {

                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        if (err) {

                        }
                    }
                });

            },
            error: function (err) {
                if (err) {

                }
            }
        });        
    });
```

The definition of my api action is like the following

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> addDocumentsOfARequest(RequestDocument[] documents)
```

The class RequestDocument is like the following:

```
public class RequestDocument
    {
        [Required]
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int DocumentID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

My WebApiConfig is like the following:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "defaultApiRoutes",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }   // Only matches if "id" is one or more digits.
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        }
    }
```

the parameter 'documents' is empty. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't nested ajax requests, the problem is that your parameter is of type `Object[]`, which is really going to work against your goals here. My recommendation is to create a class that you can use as a parameter to your API and let Web API deserializer do its' thing and map properties from the request to the request body.

Comment: I have a class called 'RequestDocument' that has properties with sets and gets. I tried passing this class instead of object but it is always empty 

public IHttpActionResult addDocumentsOfARequest(RequestDocument[] documents)

Comment: Why are you using an array? Take off `[]` Also, can you edit your question with the class definition?

Comment: Alright, when i tried to take off the [] and it did catch only the first document .. the thing is I need to have a some sort of 'documents' collection so I can loop through and all the documents in the same request

Comment: I'm not sure where you are at this point since you didn't update your question. Are you still using `Object[]`? (assuming you aren't)

Comment: oh.. I just did :)

Comment: Where is the class definition for `RequestDocument` ?

Comment: I just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my exact working code :

### Server

```
public class GamesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(RequestDocument[] document)
        {
            var req = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Ok();
        }
    }

public class RequestDocument
    {
        [Required]
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int DocumentID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

### JavaScript

```
var documents = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var RequestDocument = {
            "RequestID": i,
            "DocumentID": i+1,
            "StartDate": Date(),
            "EndDate": Date()
        };

        documents.push(RequestDocument);

    }


    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:1757/api/games",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(documents),
        success: function(a, b) {
            alert("Done");
        }
    });
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mark, I will test this out and let you know :)

Comment: Nothing is jumping out to me in your code why it wouldn't work with multiple `RequestDocument`s .. So I'm not sure if that was an issue still or not.

Comment: When I am debugging the code.. the param 'document' in the server side is empty '{A.Models.RequestDocument[0]}'
I updated my question

Comment: Something odd is going on then. Do you have any bad data or anything? Can you just copy my javascript code and see if it works?

Comment: I copied the for loop that you used to fill up the documents array .. but the param in the server side is still empty .. I feel like I am missing something .. when I took off the '[]' then it caught something

Comment: I believe you Mark .. but I don't know what am I doing wrong .. I updated my code in the question

Comment: What's your WebApiConfig class look like?

Comment: I don't think this will have anything to do with it, but add `[Route("api/requests/addDocumentsOfARequest")]` as an attribute above your method declaration. I am running out of ideas haha

Comment: I will, and thank you so much for your efforts and time :))))

Comment: and there aren't any errors in the Console are there?

Comment: Mark, I tried to create another action and trigger this action via another button .. I used exactly your code and it worked!!!? I don't understand why in nested ajax request it did not work!!?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then..Sorry I couldn't answer your question entirely

Comment: Mark, I have a question.. why the data that is captured in the param 'documents' has a wrong start/end dates? is it related to the class?

Comment: It is the local date/time in JavaScript on your machine

Comment: but when I console the object 'documents' the date and time are correct but when I debug the param 'documents' on the server side .. the start and end date both have the value '{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}'

Comment: I am marking your answer as the correct answer because your code is correct and all I need to add is a delay to catch the array.. don't ask me why but that's ajax :)

Comment: Damn - I'm glad you got it working. I was really stuck on what was going on.

Comment: I am very thankful for your help, you are really expert :) btw.. I am preparing a question now. I hope you'd have time to help me out with it :))

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:1757/api/games",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
            document: documents
          },
    success: function(a, b) {
        alert("Done");
    }
});
```

Comment: it did not work..the param 'documents' is still empty

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. In you second call, as per your code you are calling this "http://localhost:64611/api/requests/addDocumentsOfARequest/" api, which I think it should be "http://localhost:64611/api/requests/post/". Now if you want Post action to respond to calls like the first one, then you should add a route attribute like this, [Route("api/requests/addDocumentsOfARequest")]